# Using vim, how do you quickly refresh a web page you're working on?

Tags: linux, vim, text-editor, vi

I've been using VIM for a few weeks now while messing with various web languages and I'm really enjoying it.

I find it cumbersome having to tab or click into my browser and refresh the page to see the effect of a code change. It's even more annoying as I'm using Virtual Box and I tend to be working from PDF files on the host system so I have limited window space.

Do you gurus have any fancy ways of doing this? I was wondering if it's possible to split the VIM workspace and have links/lynx in a window of its own or something to that effect?

edit:

out of curiosity, if anyone is still glancing at this:-

is it possible to execute a browser from vim and load a URL based on a variable of sorts?

:! firefox http://localhost/bla/$CURRENTWORKINGFILE

sort of thing?

Comment: if anyone can think of a more fitting title post, please do say.

Comment: Why not use a browser on the host?

Comment: That new question... warrants a new question. But on Super User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to do this in specific, but I know of two plugins which let you communicate with a shell from within VIM:

- http://code.google.com/p/conque/
- http://technotales.wordpress.com/2007/10/03/like-slime-for-vim/

Answer (score 5):

If you are developing locally where no one cares, how about setting some JS to refresh the page?

```
<script>
setTimeout(function() { location.reload() }, 60000 );
</script>
```

That way you can keep working in vim and take a glance at the web page every min or so to see it refresh. This should work for most web pages.

I do this on dual monitors by leaving VIM open on one monitor and the browser on the other.

Answer (score 2):

Use an app called [XRefresh](http://xrefresh.binaryage.com/).

Comment: This looks excellent, although it appears to be for windows only?

I shall make use of it non-the-less as I'm switching between different environments and trying to find a comfort zone. :)

Comment: I've found this extension for Chrome as well, using Ruby. It shall work in Linux. Search for "XRefresh" on github.