# How to refresh my web browser after I save a file in VI

Tags: javascript, browser, vi

If I'm editing a javascript file in VI, I'd like it to somehow refresh the browser as soon as I save my file without me having to switch to the browser window and press F5. (I'm using a transparent terminal so I can see the browser through my code). What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I found the auto-save to be a bit cumbersome (i.e i need to install server and then plugin). A quick solution that makes things a little easier is to have my terminal always float on top of my browser. (i use a mac) see http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered here:

[Using vim, how do you quickly refresh a web page you're working on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065334/using-vim-how-do-you-quickly-refresh-a-web-page-youre-working-on)

I like the look of http://xrefresh.binaryage.com/

Comment: oops, you're right sorry about that :/ .. thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [Automatically refresh browser in response to file system changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309599/automatically-refresh-browser-in-response-to-file-system-changes)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a python script which works with all browsers and can use multiple browsers simultaneously. It currently only works on linux though. http://code.google.com/p/reloader/